# two polynomials having no gcd's in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field and let $R$ be the subring of $k[x]$ consisting of all polynomials having no linear term, that is, $f (x) \in R$ if and only if $f (x) = s_0 +s_2x^2 +s_3x^3 +\ldots + s_nx^n$.

Show that $x^5$ and $x^6$ have no gcd in $R$.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score -1):

**Hint only** as this sounds like a homework question.

- Suppose there is a gcd $g(x)=g_0+g_2x^2+g_3x^3+\cdots+g_nx^n$.
- Explain why $x^2\mid g(x)$ and $x^3\mid g(x)$.
- Find out what you can about the coefficients $g_0,\ldots\,$.
- Obtain a contradiction.